# Is there a way to convert mkv, mp4 to .avi with ffmpeg without noticable quality loss?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert some mkv and mp4 files to .avi with the libxvid codec, every time these convert the bitrate gets lowered way too much.

Comment: What value did you set for the bitrate?

Comment: I think you can use `-c:v copy`, but I am not sure I understand the question.